# Postgres - additional files in the extensions folder

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating a Postgres server to an AWS EC2 instance.

I'm trying to restore and getting the following error(s):

```
could not execute query: 
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pgcrypto": No such file or directory
```

The only thing that I find different between the old and new systems is the following directory: share/postgresql/extension has a number of additional files.Specifically, files related to pgcrypto.

Can I just copy over the additional files in the extensions folder to the new system?

Comment: You need to install postgresql-contrib-x.x. Do you build postgres from source or installed via package?

Comment: thank you, yes that is what I needed - appreciate the input - it took some digging to stumble upon it - should anyone be wondering there's a folder called contrib in the Postgres source download which you have to run a make for each of the extensions you want - then add configuration file and add the extension through psql

Comment: Glad to help you :)